# how to change jenkins email "undisclosed-participant@email.invalid"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins send an email with user named undisclosed-participant with email address "undisclosed-participant@email.invalid".
We've tried changing values in email-ext plugin and still it doesnt work to use a legit user and email address.

How can we change that to use a legit user and an email address ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Go to Manage Jenkins - Configure Systems 
>   Search for "System Admin e-mail address" 
>   Make sure it is NOT empty. 
>   Enter a legit email address. 
>   Save it  Rerun job to make sure you get email notification.